The EC2 connection was working fine but suddenly the connection timed out
`I have one bastion ec2, and I had no problem with connecting with putty, but when I tried to connect today, I couldn't connect with "Network Error : connection timed out".
I also set the pem file, and the inbound rule in the security group is 0.0.0.0/0.
Access to the web console works fine, what else should I check additionally?
pem configure
security group inbound rule
webconsole login

I can connect - obviously I don't have credentials to log in.
It's probably your local firewall or internet connection.


